# Change form field value on 'def form_invalid' using class based views

Tags: django

I'm working with a CreateView from django class based views for a form submit, and I have a special validation defined on the clean method:

```
class MyModelCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(
        label='quantity',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_quantity = kwargs.pop('initial_quantity')
        super(MyModelCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['quantity'].initial = initial_quantity

    def clean(self):
        # Don't take care of random_int definition
        if self.cleaned_data['quantity'] != random_int:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'There is a bug',
            )
```

The 'quantity' field has a default initial value (initial_quantity), and, if this number is diferent of 'random_int', the form will be invalid and the view will return the form with 'form_errors' for show to the user. Ok, in that point, I need to set the value of the 'quantity' field to 'random_int', and then, the next time that the user submits the form, the view response will be handle by the form_valid method.

I tried to edit the 'quantity' field value on the 'form_invalid' method, but is not working. The error is correctly raised but, the value of the 'quantity' field is 'initial_quantity' yet:

views.py

```
class MyModelCreateView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelCreateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyModelCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'initial_quantity': 10})
        return kwargs

    def get_form(self, form_class=MyModelCreateForm):
        form = form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        my_object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(my_object.get_absolute_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        ctx = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        random_int = random.randint(0,20)
        form.fields['quantity'].initial = random_int # Tried to change value here, but is not working
        ctx['form'] = form
        return self.render_to_response(ctx)
```

how can I edit a form field value on form invalid response? Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your problem correctly, but you may need `clean` method. Each field in forms has a clean method with special naming (`clean_fieldname`). you can override it like:

```
def clean_quantity(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
    # check anything you want here and return the desired value.
    value = self.random_int # or something else
    return value
```

More details are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.clean)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I tried it too. The error message raises correctly but the field value is initial_quantity yet. I need that at this time, the field value changes to random_int, and then if a submit the form again, I have the same error message again, and again, and agaian, because self.cleaned_data['quantity'] and self.random_int will be always diferent :(.

Answer (score 0):

The reason setting `initial` on the form didn't work is because by the time the form reaches the `form_invalid` method, the form is **bound**. `initial` values are only displayed for **unbound** forms (when the form has no data).

One way to change the form's data in `form_invalid` is like this:

```
def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
    ctx = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    random_int = random.randint(0,20)
    form.data = form.data.copy()       <--- make a copy
    form.data['quantity'] = random_int <--- assign value
    ctx['form'] = form
    return self.render_to_response(ctx)
```